# React-spring useSpring() prevents viewport size from updating when window is resized

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-spring

I have made a simple animation with a search bar using react-spring's `useSpring()`. When in focus, I want the search bar to change `width`, change its `margin` to `0`, and change its `top` value to `0`.

The first issue I encounter is that the margin does not change. I don't know if this is an issue with the auto keyword, but the search bar is centred before the animation, and doesn't change.

The second issue is that when I resize the window, the `top` value and `width` value of the search bar (which are in units of `vw` and `vh`) don't update until the page is refreshed, or the search bar goes back into focus.

I've linked my code [here](https://codesandbox.io/embed/react-spring-browser-resizing-gnc0z)

Will I need to make the app `auto-refresh` on `window resize` to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first part, try using other method of centering than `margin: auto`. For example with a combination of `left: 50%; transform: translateX(-50%)` you can also center your component. And react-spring can interpolate with this values.

For the second part. Try using viewport units instead of pixels. Like `vw` and `vh`.

Something like this:

```
  const props = useSpring({
    top: focused ? `0px` : `${0.29 * window.innerHeight - 35}px`,
    width: focused
      ? `80vw`
      : `50vw`,
    margin: '10px',
    left: focused ? '40%' : '50%',
    transform: 'translateX(-50%)',
    config: { velocity: 4, mass: 1.8 }
  });
```

Full example: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-spring-browser-resizing-mm7d1